Regex - how to match a line between two optional characters that are not included in group?
The regex should match

/exampleline - match exampleline
exampleline - match exampleline
exampleline/ - match exampleline
/exampleline/ - match exampleline

I tried ?\/(.+)\/? but it didn't work
/exampleline/ and exampleline/ matched exampleline/, instead of exampleline

Why don't you just search for "exampleline"?  It seems like the delimiters are irrelevant here.

It's just an example. I want to match any string between /'s

What about [^\s/]+ https://regex101.com/r/pZmxDa/1

This wouldn't work if there's a slash somewhere in the middle (I want to include these). Guess I should have been more precise in my question.

You can use negative lookarounds to assert that a match does not start with and does not end with a /:
(?!/).+(?<!/)

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/EKOvzG/2

This works, thanks

This seems very odd.  What you really want here, apparently, is just the input string with any leading or trailing / removed.  That's not really a regular expression problem at all, is it?

Yes, it could be solved with a simple if clause. However, it also frustrated me that I couldn't find a regex to solve such a simple problem.

It is necessary to remove the symbol "/" from the group. Try this:
\/?([^\/]+)\/?


You can match any character except /. Then optionally match a part that matches the whole line ending on a character other than /
[^/\n](?:.*[^/\n])?

The pattern matches:

[^/\n] Match a character other than a newline or /
(?: Non capture group to make the whole part optional

.* Match the whole line
[^/\n] Match a character other than a newline or /


)? Close the non capture group and make it optional

See a regex demo
If the match should start and end with a non whitespace character, you can replace the \n with \s
[^/\s](?:.*[^/\s])?

See another regex demo
